# How big a bean bag?

Tags: support-equipment

I think a beanbag could be useful as a camera support. But it seems they are available in a variety of shapes and sizes.

How big do you need? Presumably it depends on the size of the camera and lens.

And what shape - square, or long and thin, or round? How thick does it need to be?

Comment: It rather depends on whether it's only for the camera, or to sit on. Whether you need to carry it yourself halfway up a mountain, or have a grips to bring it from the van 10 yards away... I think you need to clarify your intended purpose.

Comment: How many beans do you have?

Comment: Depends if you use it for complete support or for assistive support, meaning that you would still be holding the camera such as is often done to shoot above a jeep door on Safari.

Comment: If you have a truly solid base to put it on and/or keep hold of the camera you can get away with a surprisingly small bean bag (even if you have to use something else as well. If not, or if you want to see over a lip (e.g. wildlife hide window) you might be surprised at how big you need.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement is that it hold the equipment without shifting or getting in the way. This leaves you with a wide range of usable sizes. You might need to consider the surface you'll be resting the beanbag on too. Experimentation is probably the best solution.